# Webshop design javascript/php

Tags: web, webshop

I have a simple question regarding the design of a web shopping process. 
I want to implement a website where you can first design your own product based on templates by going through different steps. You have breadcrumbs for that purpose in the header. How should the steps be implemented? Should I only create one website e.g. prototyp.php and dynamically change the ui-elements on that side for every step? Or should I implement one site for each step of design process and always give the data to the succeeding site?

Greets
Michbeck

Answer (score 0):

It works in both ways. I decided to built only one php site and make it change dynamically via javascript from stept to step.